# Change Twig cache file permissions to clear cache

Tags: php, linux, caching, twig, file-permissions

On the webserver I am working on, Twig 1.27 creates cache files with the Apache user and the permissions 755.

```
$ ls -la cache/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 5 apache       apache         33 Jan 31 09:40 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 apache       apache         4096 Jan 31 02:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache       apache         81 Jan 31 09:40 08
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache       apache         81 Jan 31 09:40 4e
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache       apache         81 Jan 31 09:40 92
```

I would like to clear the cache without obtaining su rights through a script. So I looked into the Twig files and found that it actually is set to write them with the permissions 777.

lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php

```
public function write($key, $content)
{
    $dir = dirname($key);
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        if (false === @mkdir($dir, 0777, true) && !is_dir($dir)) {
```

Why is Apache not writing the dirs/files with the 777 permissions?
Alternatively is there a build in way in Twig to clear the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the way I initially thought to solve the problem but it works.
I added a script to my rc.local that uses **inotifywait** to check if any new file or changes on existing files within my twig template folder have happened. If true the cache will be cleared. 
I added the exclusion for vi swap files to not trigger the the script when opening a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  inotifywait -e modify -r /var/www/project/tpl/ @/var/www/project/tpl/cache --excludei ".swp"
  rm -rf /var/www/project/tpl/cache/*
done
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no builtin way to clear cache, but instead of changing the core file of twig I have another solution for this problem. Just create your own `Environment`which extends of `Twig_Environment` and adjust the `writeCacheFile` function and make an instance for your custom instance rather than the default `Twig_Environment`.

```
class Environment extends \Twig_Environment {
    protected function writeCacheFile($file, $content){
        $this->createDirectoryTree(dirname($file));
        parent::writeCacheFile($file, $content);
        chmod($file,0664);
    }

    protected function createDirectoryTree($folder) {
        if (is_dir($folder)) return;

        $folder = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $folder);
        $branches = array_filter(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $folder));

        $tree = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if (strpos($folder, 'httpdocs') !== false)  while(!empty($branches) && strpos($tree, 'httpdocs') === false) $tree .= array_shift($branches).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        while(is_dir($tree)) $tree .= array_shift($branches).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        array_unshift($branches, pathinfo($tree, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $tree = realpath(dirname($tree)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if ($tree === null) return;

        $old_mask = umask(0);
        while(!empty($branches)) {
            $tree .= array_shift($branches).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            if (!@file_exists($tree)) @mkdir($tree, 0775);
        }
        umask($old_mask);
    }


}
```

---

*note: using `0777` as file permissions is considered a security thread and is not recommended*

Comment: Hi DarkBee,
I did not change the core file I just discovered that it is already supposed to write the files with the permissions 777. So I am wondering, why it is not doing it.

Comment: Mike, you are right. That's why I created this class, trying to recall why it was. Let me think about this again

Comment: @Mike, I've updated the code with my real class, it seems my server wasn't quite fund of the recursive `mkdir` twig is using in their function `writeCacheFile`

Comment: thank you for the update on your answer. But where would I store your class so that Twig loads it and extends its own classes?

Comment: Are you using twig standalone or with another framework?

Comment: as standalone currently

Comment: You would do `$twig = new Environment(...);` instead of `$twig = new \Twig_Environment(...);` - that's all

Comment: ok hopefully last question, do you put this into the Twig/Environment.php or its own file?

Comment: not in the `vendor` folder, mine is located in `Base\Twig` for example. It could be you need to change this line of code btw `if (strpos($folder, 'httpdocs') !== false)  while(!empty($branches) && strpos($tree, 'httpdocs') === false) $tree .= array_shift($branches).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` to the root folder of your vhost (prolly `www` instead of `httpdocs`)

Comment: Unfortunatily I am not sure how correctly load the class . When putting it into a seperate file in my project. And then include it after including the Twig autoloader I still get an error that the class that I want to extend can not be found: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig_Environment' not found